# php.ini not allowing me to disable_functions

Tags: php, windows, apache

I put this in the php.ini file:

```
disable_functions="popen,exec,system,passthru,proc_open,shell_exec,show_source,phpinfo"
```

But I can still call them (tested exec and shell_exec. I have restarted the webserver several times.

(under windows).

Comment: the best way to see the actual php.ini settings in effect, is to call phpinfo() and see what has been set

Comment: it says "no value", I don't get it

Comment: check under the "loaded php.ini file", if it's the same path you have actually changed

Comment: I can turn safe mode on and off with that php.ini. Yes its the correct path.

Comment: try removing the double quotes, leaving the comma-separated list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing the double quotes:

```
disable_functions=popen,exec,system,passthru,proc_open,shell_exec,show_source,phpinfo
```

Comment: it's pretty hilarious that this answer is exactly the opposite of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387209/php-disable-functions-in-user-ini-file-gives-no-value-in-phpinfo-output

Comment: @anarcat nevertheless, this is the correct answer, see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php for an example