# PHP disable_functions in .user.ini file gives "no value" in phpinfo() output

Tags: php-ini, php

I put the following code in .user.ini file under apache virtual host document root. And when I view the phpinfo() output, the disable_functions fields says "no value". Please help me to figure out why.

(The "memory_limit" and "max_execution_time" are setting correctly.)

Thanks in advance.

```
memory_limit = 2048M
max_execution_time = 3600
disable_functions = apache_child_terminate,apache_get_modules,apache_getenv,apache_note,apache_setenv,curl_multi_exec,define_syslog_variables,disk_free_space,diskfreespace,dl,fpassthru,ftp_connect,ftp_exec,ftp_get,ftp_login,ftp_nb_fput,ftp_put,ftp_raw,ftp_rawlist,get_current_user,getmyuid,highlight_file,ini_alter,ini_get_all,ini_restore,link,ini_set,mysql_list_dbs,openlog,parse_ini_file,passthru,pclose,pcntl_exec,pfsockopen,php_uname,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_signal,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_wtermsig,popen,posix_getgrgid,posix_getpwuid,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_setuid,posix_uname,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,socket_accept,socket_bind,socket_create,socket_create_listen,socket_create_pair,socket_listen,shell_exec,show_source,socket_select,socket_strerror,stream_select,syslog,symlink,system
```

Answer (score 2):

@Charles is right, the PHP Manual clearly states that *disable_functions* can only be set in the master *php.ini*. This clearly defeats per-vhost custom value.

There's a workaround for this if you have uopz PECL extension enabled. Check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305274/disable-functions-local-value-ignored-when-configured-with-php-path-section/28506144#28506144) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose that with "

```
disable_functions = "apache_child_terminate,apache_get_modules,apache_getenv,apache_note,apache_setenv,curl_multi_exec,define_syslog_variables,disk_free_space,diskfreespace,dl,fpassthru,ftp_connect,ftp_exec,ftp_get,ftp_login,ftp_nb_fput,ftp_put,ftp_raw,ftp_rawlist,get_current_user,getmyuid,highlight_file,ini_alter,ini_get_all,ini_restore,link,ini_set,mysql_list_dbs,openlog,parse_ini_file,passthru,pclose,pcntl_exec,pfsockopen,php_uname,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_signal,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_wtermsig,popen,posix_getgrgid,posix_getpwuid,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_setuid,posix_uname,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,socket_accept,socket_bind,socket_create,socket_create_listen,socket_create_pair,socket_listen,shell_exec,show_source,socket_select,socket_strerror,stream_select,syslog,symlink,system"
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is not working. And when I put the same function list in the global php.ini file, it is working. So the format is correct. But I want different apache virtual host has different disable_functions list, that is why I cannot put it into the global php.ini

Comment: i doubt this is the right answer, this one is exactly the opposite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16799401/1174784

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the [php.ini derective page](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) carefully and I found `disable_function`'s changeable field is `php.ini only`. So it will only be changed inside the global php.ini file. And I am afraid that I have to find another way to implement my requirement. If anybody can give me some suggestion about how to assign different disable_functions list to different apache vritual hosts, that will be super helpful. Cheers.